# Wordpress custom post type URL includes /blog/ after domain name

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, blogs, permalinks

I have set up a custom post type called projects. When a project is viewed this is the URL its is on:
http://example.com/blog/projects/project-number-one
But I want it to display without /blog like this:
http://example.com/projects/project-number-one

My permalink structure is:
/blog/%postname%/

If I remove /blog from the permalink structure then the project URLs are correct:
http://example.com/projects/project-number-one

But then my blogposts look like this (with out /blog):
http://example.com/blog-post

What I wound like is my blog posts' ULRs to look like this:
http://example.com/blog/blog-post
And my projects to be like this:
http://example.com/projects/project-number-one

```
// This is my custom post type code:

function custom_post_type_projects() {

    $labels = array(
        'name'                  => 'Projects',
        'singular_name'         => 'Project',
        'menu_name'             => 'Projects',
        'name_admin_bar'        => 'Projects',
        'archives'              => 'Projects',
        'attributes'            => 'Projects Attributes',
        'parent_item_colon'     => 'Parent Project:',
        'all_items'             => 'All Project pages',
        'add_new_item'          => 'Add New Project / Project Page',
        'add_new'               => 'Add New',
        'new_item'              => 'New Project / Project Page',
        'edit_item'             => 'Edit Project / Project Page',
        'update_item'           => 'Update Project / Project Page',
        'view_item'             => 'View Project / Project Page',
        'view_items'            => 'View Projects',
        'search_items'          => 'Search Project / Project Pages',
        'not_found'             => 'Not found',
        'not_found_in_trash'    => 'Not found in Trash',
        'featured_image'        => 'Featured Image',
        'set_featured_image'    => 'Set featured image',
        'remove_featured_image' => 'Remove featured image',
        'use_featured_image'    => 'Use as featured image',
        'insert_into_item'      => 'Insert into Project page',
        'uploaded_to_this_item' => 'Uploaded to this item',
        'items_list'            => 'Projects list',
        'items_list_navigation' => 'Projects list navigation',
        'filter_items_list'     => 'Filter Projects list',
    );
    $args = array(
        'label'                 => 'Project',
        'description'           => 'Projects',
        'labels'                => $labels,
        'supports'              => array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'page-attributes', 'revisions', 'excerpt'),
        'hierarchical'          => true,
        'public'                => true,
        'show_ui'               => true,
        'show_in_menu'          => true,
        'menu_position'         => 5,
        'menu_icon'             => 'dashicons-format-gallery',
        'show_in_admin_bar'     => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus'     => true,
        'can_export'            => true,
        'has_archive'           => 'projects',
        'exclude_from_search'   => false,
        'publicly_queryable'    => true,
        'capability_type'       => 'page',
        'show_in_rest' => true
    );
    register_post_type( 'projects', $args );

}
add_action( 'init', 'custom_post_type_projects', 0 );
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your $args

```
'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'projects','with_front' => false),
```